# How to create li element after click ReactJS

Tags: html, css, reactjs

I have two inputs and one button. After pressing the button I want to take the value from both inputs and create a li element with that value. The Li element should be created in the ul list which is at the bottom of the code. Inputs and button are marked with bold text. I tried to create a function to create li element also on value of input but it didn't work

```
import { useState } from 'react';
import './App.css';

function App() {

  const [income , setIncome] = useState(0) 
  const expense = 10 
  const balance = income - expense
  const [firtValue , setFirtValue] = useState("")
  const [secValue , setSecValue] = useState("")

  const hadnleChane = event => {
    setSecValue(event.target.value)
  }

  const hadnleChan = event => {
    setFirtValue(event.target.value)
  }

  function handleChange(event) {
    setIncome(event.target.value)
  }

  const listOfLi = () =>{
    return(
      <li>{firtValue}</li>
    )
  }

  function maxLengthCheck (object){
    if (object.target.value.length > object.target.maxLength) {
     object.target.value = object.target.value.slice(0, object.target.maxLength)
      }
    }

  function handleClick() {
    listOfLi()
  }

  return (
    <div >

      <header>
        <div className='App'>
        Expense Tracker
        </div>
      </header>

      <main className='main'>

        <div className='income-box'>

          <div className='income'>Income

            <div className='numbers'>
              {income + "$"}
            </div>

          </div>

          <div className='expense'>Expense

            <div className='numbers'>
              {expense + "$"}
            </div>

          </div>

        </div>

        <div className='income-input'>
          <input type="number" min="0" maxLength = "8" onInput={maxLengthCheck} className='input' placeholder='Enter your Income' onChange={handleChange}/>
        </div>

        <div className='total-balance'>
          Total Balance : {balance}$
        </div>

        **<div className='add-item'>Item
          <input type="text" className='adding-input' placeholder='Add Item' onChange={hadnleChane}/>
        </div>

        <div className='add-item'>Amount
          <input type="number" className='adding-input' placeholder='Add Amount' onChange={hadnleChan}/>
        </div>

        <div className='add-button'>
          <button type="button" className='expense-button' onClick={handleClick}>Add Expense</button>
        </div>**

        <div>
          <ul>
            {listOfLi}
          </ul>
        </div>

      </main>
      
    </div>
  );
}

export default App;
```

Answer (score 0):

Have a state that stores the values for the `<li>`s:

```js
const [values, setValues] = useState([]);
```

For the `<button>` `onClick` handler, append the `firtValue` and `secValue` to the state:

```js
function handleClick() {
  setValues(values.concat(`${firtValue} ${secValue}`));
}
```

Have the `listOfLi` be constructed as a map of `values`:

```js
const listOfLi = values.map((value, i) => <li key={i}>{value}</li>);
```

Putting it all together:

```
import { useState } from 'react';

function App() {
  const [income, setIncome] = useState(0);
  const expense = 10;
  const balance = income - expense;
  const [firtValue, setFirtValue] = useState('');
  const [secValue, setSecValue] = useState('');
  const [values, setValues] = useState([]);

  const hadnleChane = (event) => {
    setSecValue(event.target.value);
  };

  const hadnleChan = (event) => {
    setFirtValue(event.target.value);
  };

  function handleChange(event) {
    setIncome(event.target.value);
  }

  function maxLengthCheck(object) {
    if (object.target.value.length > object.target.maxLength) {
      object.target.value = object.target.value.slice(
        0,
        object.target.maxLength
      );
    }
  }

  function handleClick() {
    setValues(values.concat(`${firtValue} ${secValue}`));
  }

  const listOfLi = values.map((value, i) => <li key={i}>{value}</li>);

  return (
    <div>
      <header>
        <div className="App">Expense Tracker</div>
      </header>

      <main className="main">
        <div className="income-box">
          <div className="income">
            Income
            <div className="numbers">{income + '$'}</div>
          </div>

          <div className="expense">
            Expense
            <div className="numbers">{expense + '$'}</div>
          </div>
        </div>

        <div className="income-input">
          <input
            type="number"
            min="0"
            maxLength="8"
            onInput={maxLengthCheck}
            className="input"
            placeholder="Enter your Income"
            onChange={handleChange}
          />
        </div>

        <div className="total-balance">Total Balance : {balance}$</div>

        <div className="add-item">
          Item
          <input
            type="text"
            className="adding-input"
            placeholder="Add Item"
            onChange={hadnleChane}
          />
        </div>

        <div className="add-item">
          Amount
          <input
            type="number"
            className="adding-input"
            placeholder="Add Amount"
            onChange={hadnleChan}
          />
        </div>

        <div className="add-button">
          <button
            type="button"
            className="expense-button"
            onClick={handleClick}
          >
            Add Expense
          </button>
        </div>

        <div>
          <ul>{listOfLi}</ul>
        </div>
      </main>
    </div>
  );
}

export default App;
```